# Transparent Frame works correctly in Windows, but not in Linux

Tags: java, linux, jframe, transparent

The following code results in a transparent window in Windows (8.1), but an opaque window in Ubuntu (14.04). How can I achieve the transparent window with the red outline in Ubuntu 14.04?

My goal is to create an undecorated window with 'rounded (transparent) edges', so the setOpacity() method won't help since that will affect the full window, even though it does work on both operating systems.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    f.setUndecorated(true);
    f.setBackground(new Color(0,255,0,0));
    f.setSize(512, 512);
    f.add(new JPanel() {
        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            g.setColor(Color.RED);
            g.drawRect(0, 0, 511, 511);
        }
    });
    f.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: Have you [How to Implement a Shaped Window](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/trans_shaped_windows.html#shaped)? Compound it with [`RoundRectangle2D`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/RoundRectangle2D.html)

Comment: @peeskillet Window shape does work on both, but then you have those rough edges from lack of anti-aliasing. The Ubuntu window still fills the green background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the source of the problem. It is related to having a multi-monitor setup in Ubuntu. Regardless, here's the solution--which will cause it to work on the favored monitor:

Add the following code before the setVisible() call:

```
    f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
```

I think the reason it failed is because the frame may have been rendered on the secondary monitor first (due to different resolutions per monitor?), which may have resulted in this drawing error.

Thank you all for your input. It is greatly appreciated! :)

Answer (score 0):

Not all window mangers on linux support transparent windows. If a window manager does not support transparent windows t will show up as a normal window. So check first that your window manager supports transparent windows (with [GraphicsDevice#isWindowTranslucencySupported()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/GraphicsDevice.html#isWindowTranslucencySupported-java.awt.GraphicsDevice.WindowTranslucency-)).

Comment: I've tested that too. The following return true on both Windows and Ubuntu for isWindowTranslucencySupported(): WindowTranslucency.PERPIXEL_TRANSLUCENT, PERPIXEL_TRANSPARENT, TRANSLUCENT